# Creating a pythonic snippet to read and clean .csv files

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to import a .csv file, clean the contents, and make sure all the errors are eliminated.

- IO error
- file format error
- data error

I am using the snippet below.  Could someone help me clean it and make it more pythonic?

```
try:
    fl = request.FILES['csv']
except:
    return HttpResponse("Some IO Error")
try:    
    reader = csv.reader(fl)
except:
    return HttpResponse("File Not Supported")
reader.next() # this makes sure the heading is 
cleaned_csv_content = list()
for row in reader:
    err = 0
    fname, lname, e_mail  = row
    try:
        validate_email(email)
    except:
        pass
        err = 1
    if not err:
        cleaned_csv_content.append(fname, lname, e_mail)
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you should `raise` not `return` your errors.

Secondly, `try:` with a bare `except:` is bad practice (e.g. http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/); what do you expect *could* go wrong with each step? Test for specific errors and deal with them appropriately. It is this which has hidden the `NameError` I mention at the end.

Thirdly, your use of the flag `err` seems a bit odd; much more Pythonic to use an actual boolean `err = False` or, better, `else:`:

```
try:
    validate_email(e_mail) # see comment below
except: # but only the errors you expect - see above 
    pass
else:
    cleaned_csv_content.append((fname, lname, e_mail)) # note additional parentheses
```

or, even better, refactor `validate_email` to `return True` for a valid email and `False` otherwise, rather than raising errors:

```
if validate_email(e_mail):
    cleaned_csv_content.append((fname, lname, e_mail))
```

Finally, note that `"email" != "e_mail"`.

Comment: how about the for loops, can that be made more idiomatic?

Comment: No; `for row in reader:` is fine and the tuple unpacking of each `row` is very Pythonic

Comment: I am getting this error - `Error: 'line contains NULL byte'` `for row in reader` Any corrections?

Comment: Not to the code, as such; you will need to look at your input data and what is ending up in `reader`, or use another `try` and handle that specific error appropriately (e.g. `pass` on that line).

Comment: thanks done, another doubt. I am getting output of - `for row in readline:    print row` as follows 

`['First Name\tLast Name\tEmail Address']
['ASdf \tasdf\tasdf@asdf.asdf']`

The delimiter here is \t, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)! Iterative StackExchange commenting is not an appropriate way to write a programe.